# SIM868 breakout board does not accept GNSS/GPS AT commands

Tags: uart, gps, gsm, sim, gnss

I bought SIM868 breakout board with GNSS support. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33013782111.html

However, I can’t get coordinates using standard at-command AT+CGNSPWR=1, AT+CGNSTST=1, etc. I get “+CME ERROR: unknown” all the time.
I tried commands for GPS also, in case if seller was not exact.
Does anybody know how to get location with this kind of module?
PS. There are also extra UART pins for GNSS. As far as I know, there is is an alternative way to work with GNSS, however It will make to remove two resistors, what I don’t want to do.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the datasheet and/or user's manual for the board? If not then it will be difficult to help you. It might be best to discard this module and buy another that has proper documentation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson. That's the problem! Seller does not provide datasheet.I found something similar - https://www.techshopbd.com/uploads/product_document/UNV-SIM868V2.0usermanualV1.0.pdf

Comment: Try AT+CFUN=1 (it should affect only the phone radio, but maybe it somehow interacts with GPS).

Comment: @filo , Unfortunately, it AT+CFUN=1 does no effect.

Comment: Currently I am looking for kinda firmware update...